# C# Switch compare strings with OR

Tags: c#

I'm trying to do a double check of 2 functions, but how can I get it through switch:

```
                pwdStrength.SetPassword(text_passmysql.Text);
                pwdStrength1.SetPassword(text_adminpass.Text);

                switch (pwdStrength.GetPasswordStrength() || pwdStrength1.GetPasswordStrength())
                {
                    case "Very Weak":
                    case "Weak":
                        // Show an error message to the user
                        MessageBox.Show("A password do MySQL é muito fraca, escolha um mais forte.\nApenas pode alterar a password MySQL para uma mais forte, caso contrário não será guardada.", "Configurações do Programa", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                        break;
                    case "Good":
                    case "Strong":
                    case "Very Strong":
                        // Password deemed strong enough, allow user to be added to database etc
                        //do something
                        break;
                }
```

How can I do to work with the example above?

Thanks

EDIT: Got it working! Thanks @Nyerguds.

After editing the code I managed to work the solution posted by @Nyerguds.

Thanks everyone

Solution:

```
        pwdStrength.SetPassword(text_passmysql.Text);
        pwdStrength1.SetPassword(text_adminpass.Text);

        PassStrength strSql = (PassStrength)Enum.Parse(typeof(PassStrength), pwdStrength.GetPasswordStrenght1());
        PassStrength strAdm = (PassStrength)Enum.Parse(typeof(PassStrength), pwdStrength1.GetPasswordStrenght1());

        PassStrength lowest = (PassStrength)Math.Min((Int32)strSql, (Int32)strAdm);

        if ((Int32)lowest < (Int32)PassStrength.Good)
        {
            // Show an error message to the user
            MessageBox.Show("A password do MySQL é muito fraca, escolha um mais forte.\nApenas pode alterar a password MySQL para uma mais forte, caso contrário não será guardada.", "Configurações do Programa", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
        else
        {
            // Password deemed strong enough, allow user to be added to database etc
        }
```

New function:

```
    enum PassStrength
    {
        Unchecked = 0, // Enums should always have an empty value for initialisation.
        VeryWeak = 1,
        Weak = 2,
        Good = 3,
        Strong = 4,
        VeryStrong = 5
    }

    public string GetPasswordStrenght1()
    {
        string valor = GetPasswordStrength();

        switch(valor)
        {
            case "Very Weak":
                return Convert.ToString(PassStrength.VeryWeak);
            case "Weak":
                return Convert.ToString(PassStrength.Weak);
            case "Good":
                return Convert.ToString(PassStrength.Good);
            case "Strong":
                return Convert.ToString(PassStrength.Strong);
            case "Very Strong":
                return Convert.ToString(PassStrength.VeryStrong);
            default:
                return Convert.ToString(PassStrength.Unchecked);
        }
    }
```

Comment: What's the return type for the function `GetPasswordStrength` and what you are trying to achieve

Comment: I think what you're doing here isn't what you think you're doing. It looks like you want to run both pwdStrength and pwdStrength1s results through the switch, and show an error if at least 1 is "Weak" or "Very Weak"? is that correct?

Comment: why on earth one would return the strength of a password in string? what's enum for?

Comment: This seems like exactly what `Enum` was conceived for. In fact, if you give them int values depending on strength, you can just take the `Int32.Min()` of the two.

Comment: It's working now!! Thanks everyone! (I posted the solution)

Comment: @charparodar Post the solution as an answer instead of including it in the question.

Comment: Um. Why are you first converting the enum to a string and then back to enum? That makes no sense. You should just call the enum-returning `GetPasswordStrength()` directly.

Comment: @Nyerguds I don't know how to create that kind of function (enum type and return enum)...

Comment: Eh? It's just the return type. Surely you know how to make a function return something else than a string? Just change `public string GetPasswordStrenght1()` to `public PassStrength GetPasswordStrength1()` and just return the enums directly.without the "Convert.ToString" around them. If this is your own class, just change the _original_ `GetPasswordStrength` function so you never even need to bother with those strings.

Comment: @Nyerguds thanks, I had a slight ideia, but I used that a little on C++, didn't remember that on C#, even though is almost the same...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My advice, make `GetPasswordStrength()` return an Enum instead of a String. Switch-Case structures on a `String` are completely fake anyway; they just do a bunch of string compares internally, whereas an *actual* Switch-Case is actually a very elegant and super efficient operation, on CPU level.

So, to start, make your enum, and assign a 'quality' value to each of the items:

```
public Enum PassStrength
{
    Unchecked = 0, // Enums should always have an empty value for initialisation.
    VeryWeak = 1,
    Weak = 2,
    Good = 3,
    Strong = 4,
    Very Strong = 5
}
```

Return that instead of your string.

Then, since enums are integers internally, you can simply check what the lowest value between the two passwords is:

```
pwdStrength.SetPassword(text_passmysql.Text);
pwdStrength1.SetPassword(text_adminpass.Text);

PassStrength strSql = pwdStrength.GetPasswordStrength()
PassStrength strAdm = pwdStrength1.GetPasswordStrength()

PassStrength lowest = (PassStrength)Int32.MinValue((Int32)strSql, (Int32)strAdm);

if (lowest < (Int32)PassStrength.Good)
    // Give message that at least one of the passwords is too weak
Else
    // passwords are both at least "Good".
```

If you want to give specific messages on *both* (which, honestly, seems a lot more user friendly than saying "one of your passwords is too weak" without specifying which one), well, then there is obviously no other way to do that than to actually *check* both of them individually.

On a related note, do you really need the pwdStrength objects? If it only checks the strength, that seems like something a static function could do.

Comment: By the way, if you wonder "what's the difference with just using integers?", then the answer is "None at all, except that your code is a lot more clear since your integers get a name that show what each one means."

Answer (score 0):

The `||` returns boolean value, so basically your cases are only true/false. You can put the `switch` in a loop, that iterates through the passwords, and pass only 1 value at a time or extract it as a method.

```
pwdStrength.SetPassword(text_passmysql.Text);
pwdStrength1.SetPassword(text_adminpass.Text);

checkPassword(pwdStrength.GetPasswordStrength());
checkPassword(pwdStrength1.GetPasswordStrength());


public checkPassword(var pwdStrength){

    switch (pwdStrength)
    {
        case "Very Weak":
        case "Weak":
            // Show an error message to the user
            MessageBox.Show(...);
            break;
        case "Good":
        case "Strong":
        case "Very Strong":
            // Password deemed strong enough, allow user to be added to database etc
            //do something
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yep this will be a valid comment, but how it answers the question.

Answer (score 0):

You can not do that with switch, you need `if`.

```
var strength1 = pwdStrength1.GetPasswordStrength();
var strength2 = pwdStrength2.GetPasswordStrength();

if ("Weak" == strength1 || "Weak" == strength2) {
  // ... do something
}
else if ("Strong" == strength1 || "Strong" == strength2) {
  // ... do something
}
// ...
```

Answer (score 0):

The "||" operator is the *conditional* OR operator. It's used with conditions that are either true or false (boolean values).

An example:

```
if(x == y || x == z)
```

Read as: "if ( this is true OR this is true )"

So you are confusing the usage of a switch with the usage of an if-statement.

[The conditional OR operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/conditional-or-operator)

[The Switch statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/switch)

Answer (score 0):

Got it working! Thanks @Nyerguds.

After editing the code I managed to work the solution posted by @Nyerguds.

Thanks everyone

Solution:

```
    pwdStrength.SetPassword(text_passmysql.Text);
    pwdStrength1.SetPassword(text_adminpass.Text);

    PassStrength strSql = (PassStrength)Enum.Parse(typeof(PassStrength), pwdStrength.GetPasswordStrenght1());
    PassStrength strAdm = (PassStrength)Enum.Parse(typeof(PassStrength), pwdStrength1.GetPasswordStrenght1());

    PassStrength lowest = (PassStrength)Math.Min((Int32)strSql, (Int32)strAdm);

    if ((Int32)lowest < (Int32)PassStrength.Good)
    {
        // Show an error message to the user
        MessageBox.Show("A password do MySQL é muito fraca, escolha um mais forte.\nApenas pode alterar a password MySQL para uma mais forte, caso contrário não será guardada.", "Configurações do Programa", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    }
    else
    {
        // Password deemed strong enough, allow user to be added to database etc
    }
```

New function:

```
enum PassStrength
{
    Unchecked = 0, // Enums should always have an empty value for initialisation.
    VeryWeak = 1,
    Weak = 2,
    Good = 3,
    Strong = 4,
    VeryStrong = 5
}

public string GetPasswordStrenght1()
{
    string valor = GetPasswordStrength();

    switch(valor)
    {
        case "Very Weak":
            return Convert.ToString(PassStrength.VeryWeak);
        case "Weak":
            return Convert.ToString(PassStrength.Weak);
        case "Good":
            return Convert.ToString(PassStrength.Good);
        case "Strong":
            return Convert.ToString(PassStrength.Strong);
        case "Very Strong":
            return Convert.ToString(PassStrength.VeryStrong);
        default:
            return Convert.ToString(PassStrength.Unchecked);
    }
}
```

Comment: Only seeing this so much later, but... you can just let your `GetPasswordStrenght1` function return type `PassStrength` directly, instead of converting and then parsing a string.